# FullPageJS prevents touch scrolling on hamburger menu; how to integrate?

Tags: css, wordpress, fullpage.js, hamburger-menu

I have a website using the fantastic [fullPageJS](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) plugin, and it does what it does very, very well.

I have however, an issue on mobile devices, where the sliding hamburger menu does not scroll with touch controls when the menu height exceeds that of the ViewPort, as in this picture:

[image: Menu Scrolling Problem]

**Question**

How do I force the side menu to accept touch-based scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the fullpage.js option called `normalScrollElements`.

As detailed in [fullpage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> **normalScrollElements**: (default `null`) If you want to avoid the auto scroll when scrolling over some elements, this is the option you need to use. (useful for maps, scrolling divs etc.) It requires a string with the Javascript selectors for those elements. (For example: `normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2'`). This option should not be applied to any section/slide element itself.

Additionally, you can call `fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(false)` when opening the modal. That will prevent fullpage.js to scroll up or down when using the mousewheel or trackpad.

You can set it back to the default value when closing the menu by using `fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(true)`.

Comment: Wait - you are the author of the plugin? Why, thank you so much for coming to the rescue!

Comment: Yeap! That's me!

Comment: Since you are here, I'm curious - what CSS govern the ability to scroll with the touch functionality of a mobile device? I tried to alter the properties of the element myself, but to no avail.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to add `overflow: scroll` if you haven't already.

Comment: First thing I tried, of course; and it already had it. It's not so simple - it _does_ scroll with the mouse wheel, but not with the touch-simulated scrolling.

Comment: did you check the z-index?

Comment: That too. I tried all of the basic stuff - it works with a regular scrolling, just not with the touch one.

Comment: it's not working on safari and chrome on mobile? both?

Comment: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2964 have a look here!

Comment: The issue above is not relevant to my situation - I am using the full version of JQuery and the scrolling works fine - it just doesn't work for the hamburger menu.